# VUE 3 Years countdown

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, countdown, countdowntimer

I need to create a countdown for the expiration date in the VUE 3 application. I need the format of YYYY/MM/DD. my search results were using Moment.js.

After installation using:

```
npm i moment
```

I could not figure out the right way to use it.

My Code :

```
<template>
   <p> Remaining time: {{moment(moment(30-9-2022) - moment(new Date())}} 
   </p>
</template>


<script>
   import moment from "moment";

   export default {
      methods:{
         moment,
      } 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { createApp, reactive, onMounted } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  data() {
  const remaining = reactive({})
  
  onMounted(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        setTime()
    }, 1000)
    
    const eventTime = moment('2023.05.04 10:03:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss')
    
    function setTime() {
      let currenTime = moment()
      remaining.days = moment.duration(eventTime.diff(currenTime)).asDays()
      remaining.hours = moment.duration(eventTime.diff(currenTime)).get('hours')
      remaining.minutes = moment.duration(eventTime.diff(currenTime)).get('minutes')
      remaining.seconds = moment.duration(eventTime.diff(currenTime)).get('seconds')
    }
    
  })
    return {
      remaining
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="Object.keys(remaining).length > 0">
    {{ remaining.days.toFixed(0) }} :
    {{ remaining.hours.toFixed(0) }} :
    {{ remaining.minutes.toFixed(0) }} :
    {{ remaining.seconds.toFixed(0) }}
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I could not find the right usage for this particular problem through my research, so I thought it would be useful to publish it.

The Right Syntax :

````
<template>
   <p> 
      {{ getRmainTime() }}
   </p>
</template>


<script>
   import moment from "moment";

   export default {
      methods:{
          getRmainTimeToExp() {
              return `${moment
                 .duration(moment(this.user.exp_time) - moment(new 
                 Date())).years()} years, 
                 ${moment.duration(moment(this.user.exp_time) - 
                 moment(new Date())).months()} months, 
                 ${moment.duration(moment(this.user.exp_time) - 
                 moment(new Date())).days()} days`;
          },
       } 
    }
</script>


```
````